# How can I resize a div to fit all of it's contents

Tags: html, css

I have a div that's height is 75% width and 100% height but when I start to add more and more contents to the div, the div will cut off when I start to scroll as seen here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAwx4.png

I've been searching for quite a while now and still haven't found anything on how I can expand the div and not have the border cut off.

CSS for the div that I want to expand:

```
.middle {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top: 74px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

body CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
}
```

(Side note I'm very new to HTML and CSS)

Comment: I can't make any sense of that image. Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Always check its parent , and parent's parent ..etc. its 100% of its wrapper . If the wrapper was 10px , then it would be 10px .

Comment: Sorry about that, posted all of the code that I think would be relevant. In the image I provided I have a border going around the div, that's the black line that you see. The gray squares are placeholder pictures, and the second one goes over the border. That's why I want to expand the div so that the border fits all of the pictures inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but it might solve it if you add

```css
.middle {overflow: hidden;}
```

or

```css
.middle {overflow: scroll;}
```

depending on what you need.

If you need the `<div>` itself to expand to 100% of the screen's height, make sure its parent and grandparents all have 100% height as well.

Comment: I've already tried this and it's not giving me the results I want. If I were to scroll down the div gets cut off because I have the height set to 100%. I want the div to expand all the way down to the bottom of the page even when scrolled but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @Aaron In that case try giving `.middle { min-height: 100%; }` instead of `.middle { height: 100%; }`. You could also add the rest of the HTML and CSS to your question to make it clearer.